# Moving from cookie social login to token social login

Tags: asp.net, owin

This is kind of a follow on from [a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328937/owin-auth-design-for-app-that-can-authenticate-clients-or-users) I posted on programmers StackExchange, I got no answer. Maybe it was inappropriately placed and should've been here. But either way, I thrashed around some more and chopped and changed bits and now I'm closer, but need a bit more help.

I'm trying to implement Facebook logins (and later others) using Owin and the various Katana libraries. I'm only doing logins, no registering, no ASP.NET DB. I'm not using the ASP.NET Identity stuff (as in using the default ASP.NET project with individual accounts), which is what 90% of the tutorials tell you to do. Sorry if I sound frustrated. I have managed to find other people who have managed to break the mold and implemented OWIN without the identity gubbins and I've done a fair amount of reading on this. I think I just need help connecting the last few dots.

This is for an SPA with a Web API on the back end. So I naturally leaned towards bearer OAuth tokens.

I've managed to get things working in a cookie ish way, using some guidance from [this blog post](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/using-owin-external-login-without-asp-net-identity/). I immitated its approach and now I can sign in with Facebook, and when the callback action is hit, the User.Identity is successfully set to my Facebook claims identity.

The problem is, for my Web API, I want the call to auth/facebook, or by some other means, to get the OAuth bearer token of my identity to the user to use for future requests, rather than a cookie.

Am I best off going from this cookie to a token in some way? And how? Or is there a better approach for this?

Here's my Startup.cs code

```
public class Startup
{
    // public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        // other standard stuff (I think)
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // lots of commented out code of me trying to do this using a custom provider and OAuth

        var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("api/auth/facebook")
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = fbAppID,
            AppSecret = fbAppSecret,
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my auth controller code.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("facebook")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFacebookChallenge()
    {
        return new ChallengeResult("Facebook", "api/auth/callback", this.Request);
    }

    [Route("callback")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Callback()
    {
        var info = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
        return Ok(info);
    }
}
```

Currently, the callback action returns null, as info is null, but the User.Identity is set with the proper claims, all well and good. A previous implementation had it in a state where the callback wouldn't have the User.Identity authenticated, but it could retrieve an external login claims identity. But again, I couldn't get authenticated and get a token out of that. Was I closer with that approach?

Sorry for the long question. If you need me to post more of my code, please let me know, I've tried to cut down on it for brevity.

Comment: as per quick review of your question seems like you have a problem with cookie .. the token stored in cookie and you want to get that token use in server-side instead of cookie right ?

Comment: Hi, with apps iv'e worked on like this I store the cookie or auth tokens in the SPA and consequently transmit it with subsequent HTTP XHR requests as a custom header (X-HTTP-AUTH-TOKEN={cookiedata}. In my case these token are quite small, so not good if tokens are large.
I always land up creating a custom authentication handler and here. you we have 2 options. You can re-validate that token with Facebook, or whatever identity provider you use,  on every request. Or, as in my case, you trust this token for some time in your database .